# Best way to comunicate between ASP.NET app and Worker Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I have both ASP.NET app and Worker Role set up and now I wonder how do I communicate between them? I think that the idea is that the solution will be distributed across different geographic locations. So how do I link the distributed Worker and Web Roles in a simple and efficient way?
I have started to look into WCF, but it looks to me to be an overkill and overcomplicated. Another thought I had is to use SignalR client inside the Worker roles to talk with the server in the Web roles.

**EDIT:**

The exact context:

1)User uploads file to the server

2)Server sends file to Azure Storage and adds the file name to CloudQueue

3)Worker gets the file name from CloudQueue

4)Worker starts a new Thread that gets the file from Azure Storage and starts processing it

5)Worker/Thread reports back to the application at every step of the file processing

6)The application receives the reports and uses SignalR to forward the processing steps to the client's browser in real time.

What I am missing is at steps 2 > 3, How to immediately notify the Worker that a new file has arrived? I don't want to poll the CloudQueue because it will create delays.
Also at steps 5 > 6, Worker needs to notify the application about the steps and this should be without delay, but again I don't see how a polling solution can be used in such case.

Comment: A little more context on what your app is doing would be helpful; what's the nature of the communication, scale required, fire-and-forget or exact-once invocation, point-to-point or pub/sub, etc.  In general you want to strive for as little coupling as possible, so that's where queuing mechanisms like Windows Azure queues and Service Bus queues come in.  BTW, WCF is a wrapper or a lot of technologies some which are quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS stated above, a little bit more context is needed. You basically have two main options, Windows Azure Queues and Windows Azure Service Bus Queues/Topics. My personal advice would be to use Azure Queues if the Web and Worker Roles are colocated in the same region and Service Bus Queues if they are not. I would have to ask why are you not colocating your Web and Worker Roles together, if you have a geographic deployment of you app then look at deploying all your Web Roles and Work Roles in each Region e.g. US, Europe & Asia and then use Traffic Manager to  route user to the optimal region.

There is a good blog post on when to use which queue 'Windows Azure Queues and Windows Azure Service Bus Queues - Compared and Contrasted': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx

HTH

**EDIT**

A good approach for Web and Worker Role communication is below (I stole this from a recent thread which @smarx answered)

1 Web role writes a message to the queue that includes a job ID.

2 Worker role does the work and writes the result to a table with partition key .

3 Web role is polling that row of the table. Once it exists, the answer comes back.

In your case you could have the Worker Role update the Table Storage with the status updates and then have your Web Role pick them up and display them to the user. e.g. 20%, 50%, Complete etc...

I don't really see delays in this type of communication, as long as you are polling sufficiently from the Web Role (*note transactions costs)

I presume some sort of Inter Role communication could be done here for status updates but it might be overkill IMO:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180158.aspx

Comment: The whole point of my question is how to avoid polling. Polling is done at intervals, whereas I want to achieve high responsiveness close to real time.

Comment: Take a look at this thread where @smarx talks about Socket communication using synchronous communication and skipping the queue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031931/azure-queues-creation-best-practice-and-scale

Comment: Thanks, here is a good link I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at CQRS, which stands for Command Query Responsibility Segregation.

The purpose of this architecture is to create systems that are loosely coupled, extensible, and scalable.

http://cqrsjourney.github.com/

Greg Young invented this system and there are a number of open source implementations available to expedite the building of distributed, scalable systems.  Before him was Bertrand Meyer, who laid the groundwork.

The oversimplified concept is that a series of queues separate web roles and worker roles. So when users submit work from a web role, that work gets queued up, and later picked up by a worker role. A trade off is that there is eventual data consistency, not immediate consistency. The benefit is that it is loosely coupled and scalable. If the queue starts to grow too big, additional worker roles can be added to handle the additional scale.

The approach uses concepts like Commands, Queries, Domain objects. CQRS is becoming an extremely powerful way to accomplish the goals I think you are seeking.

A search engine can give you many good resources. Here are some useful videos:
Greg Young
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXqrBySgX-s
My Friend Rinat
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnvO_nlvrps

Good luck!

Comment: Looks to me that this is another redundant product from Microsoft. Went over their homepage, bunch of text about nothing. I am wondering what is the difference between Azure Storage Queues and this CQRS... I find this to be a big issue with MS that they keep spitting out redundant products, that no one knows what they are for. There are too many people working there and they have to keep themselves occupied and the result is all these products that no one ever uses.

Comment: CQRS has got nothing to do with a MSFT product, it an industry standard pattern on which MSFT are providing guidance on, on how to use it in Windows Azure. Take a look at Martin Fowler blog post on it if you want to know more. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html I suggest you open up a new thread on the difference between Azure Storage Queues and CQRS...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the azure table storage as a place to communicate between worker role and web role. Basically, Worker role will store the message/notification into azure table and in web role will have a timer to periodically checking the changes in azure table. After that web role will use SignalR to send messasge to client pages in real time to report the progress.

Global.asax.cs file:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;

protected void Application_Start()
{
     //Start the timer job
     _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
     _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WebRoleTimerJob);
     _timer.Start();
}


/// <summary>
/// This event will be fired intervally every 3 seconds to broadcast messsage to all registered client pages using SignalR
/// </summary>        
public static void WebRoleTimerJob(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{               
      // Here, you can read Azure table storage to detect any changes    
      // or notification from Worker role
      // ....

      //If there is any changes, then broadcast message 
      // to all relevant client pages using SignalR   

      var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub>();       
      context.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage("your_message_name", "message_content");
}
```